# Ruby - I need next iteration of each as my method argument

Tags: ruby

I need to write a code which recognizes sections in text

```
lines.each do |line|
  case line.match
    when :chapter
      chapter = analyze_chapter(line)
      previous = chapter
    when :section
      section = analyze_section(line)
      previous.sections<< section
      previous = section
    end
  end
```

etc., for different elements.
Example of `analyze_chapter` :

```
def analyze_chapter(chapter_line)
  Chapter.new(
    title: chapter_line.title,
    sections: [analyze_section(chapter_line)]
    )    
end
```

The problem is my input looks like this:

```
Chapter 1 - name
Section 1 - name
```

How my code works: I use regular expressions to recognize title patterns. Then, I take this matched title and save it as `title` attribute of `Line` object.
It works fine in my different code, where I was recognizing

```
Chapter 1 - name, Rest of the text - everything in one line
```

But obviously now I need to pass next line to  `sections[analyze_sections(chapter_line)]` - I kind of need next iteration, because `Chapter title` and `Section title` aren't in one line.
I know it's probably some logic error here. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: is `analyze_section` and `analyze_sections` supposed to be the same method?  Are all sections after a chapter belonging to that chapter?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. And yes, every Section after Chapter belongs to it - until next Chapter appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you're very close to what you want... this would give you an array of Chapter objects, each object including an array of sections.

```
chapters = []
lines.each do |line|
  case line.match
    when :chapter
      chapters << analyze_chapter(line)
    when :section
      chapters.last.sections << analyze_section(line)
    end
  end
end
```

The only potential problem would be if the very first line is a `:section` without a preceding `:chapter`... if that's not possible it's not something you need to code for, if it is, you may need a method that will create a "title-less " chapter.

```
chapters = []
lines.each do |line|
  case line.match
    when :chapter
      chapters << analyze_chapter(line)
    when :section
      chapters << create_missing_chapter if chapters.empty?
      chapters.last.sections << analyze_section(line)
    end
  end
end

def create_missing_chapter
    Chapter.new(
    title: "My First Chapter",
    sections: []
    )   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the chapter with all of its sections at once, you have to create a chapter with an empty sections array and fill it afterwards. Something like this:

```
require 'ostruct'
Chapter = Section = OpenStruct   # <- just for demonstration purposes

lines = <<-TEXT.split("\n")
Chapter 1 - Recurrent Problems
Section 1 - The Tower of Hanoi
Section 2 - Lines in the Plane
Section 3 - The Josephus Problem
TEXT

chapters = []
lines.each do |line|
  case line
  when /^Chapter (\d+) - (.+)$/
    chapters << Chapter.new(number: $1, title: $2, sections: [])
  when /^Section (\d+) - (.+)$/
    chapters.last.sections << Section.new(number: $1, title: $2)
  end
end
```

The above fills a `chapters` array which `Chapter` instances, each having a `sections` array attribute containing `Section` instances:

```
chapters.each do |chapter|
  puts "#{chapter.number} #{chapter.title}"
  chapter.sections.each do |section|
    puts "  #{chapter.number}.#{section.number} #{section.title}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
1 Recurrent Problems
  1.1 The Tower of Hanoi
  1.2 Lines in the Plane
  1.3 The Josephus Problem
```